# I still receives this error, but everything looks good, and migrations work correctly

Tags: php, mysql

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
> update  a child row a foreign key constraint fails
> (`ecommercewebsite`.`products`, CONSTRAINT
> `products_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES
> `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert
> into `products` (`name`, `slug`, `short_description`, `description`,
> `regular_price`, `SKU`, `stock_status`, `quantity`, `image`,
> `category_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (aut alias
> voluptates magnam deserunt non,
> aut-alias-voluptates-magnam-deserunt-non, Totam aut consequatur
> occaecati eos. Dolore eos facilis quis voluptate debitis accusamus.
> Nulla inventore consequatur repudiandae quas qui dignissimos placeat.,
> Aspernatur recusandae omnis animi. Est  qui at animi doloribus quos.
> Doloremque fugit et consequatur minus ratione sunt fugiat. Suscipit
> laborum inventore sunt non nostrum placeat., 156, PRD201, instock, 48,
> product-3, 2, 2023-05-01 05:47:51, 2023-05-01 05:47:51))

How to solve this problem??

Comment: I actually doubt that whatever your operation is meant to do in your database actually foes what you expect. That error is crystal clear: the operation cannot do what it has to do (add or update an entry) due to the issue with the foreign constraint. It does not make that error up somehow.

Comment: Check the records you have in the categories table and make sure the category_id exists.

Comment: `everything looks good`...not according to SQL. Have another look.